# Is helping a female in a accident allowed

Tags: sharia

I was recently at an accident scene with my friends, A school-girl hit by a bike, My friends and I rushed to help her, She had hurt her ankle, and my friend assisted her to walk for few steps until she got hold of her breath.

My question is it permissible to help stand the female in a condition, where she is being accompanied by a mahram who too might be involved in the accident.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you not help?   This has nothing to do with religion.

Comment: @masfenix, actually I should have reworded the question, 'it is about a situation not so serious to ask help but enough to grab attention', the example I provided is true and is there just to help elaborate the question. I would have and did help as well, but the situation demanded it. otherwise if it would have been just an attention catcher I was a bit confused regarding that, and didn't wan't to do something untoward and eerie.

Comment: It would be really helpful to this SE community, if the question is reworded as per the above comment as I couldn't come up with anything much better **(english is not my primary language)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be unethical if you don't. Each Muslim has the task of helping anybody ([5:2](http://quran.com/5/2)).

It depends always on your intention. If there is an accident and your intention is "help somebody" than I don't see any qualms. Otherwise you could ask the (female) person if it's OK to help her.

Comment: if you could provide a hadith or narration, related to this question it would be encouraged.

Comment: @yawar: unfortunately I'm not so familiar with hadith, but as I mentioned in my answer you can have a look at 5:2, Sura Maida and Ayah 2: **...Help ye one another in righteousness and piety, but help ye not one another in sin and rancour: fear Allah: for Allah is strict in punishment.**

Comment: Down vote, as answer is based on Only one verse, rejecting all the rest of the rulings of islam.

Answer (score 2):

“If a woman is in need of medical examination to treat her disease and the non-mahram doctor is better equipped to treat her, that doctor is allowed to look at her body and touch it if need be. If it is possible to treat her by either of the two methods (looking or touching), he [should restrict himself to one and] would not be allowed to use the other [method].”

From this opinion of the scholars, we can conclude that if there is an emergency and a female is in need of examination of wound or to be taken to hospital, non mahram can do so only to the extend of helping her.

Source::> http://www.sistani.org/english/book/46/2065/

Answer (score 1):

"assisted her to walk for few steps until she got hold of her breath"
- so, only few steps, so she even did not need that help. so in this case he should not help her, (because there was not a serious need).

even in case this happens, he should try to do not touch her skin, and more, even should try to support her only through big, rough material or a stick, because feeling her body through cloth is also intimate, feeling awrah.

Comment: would you to like to rethink about the answer. Those helping reactions develop all of a sudden in people. They don't have time to calculate whether to help or not because she's a girl. It comes voluntarily I guess. Even at that time, you can do the work by just catching her hands and not even her shoulders. Depends on the situation.

Comment: if it is sudden reaction than he should plan to not do it next time and blame himself for he has not realised this timely this time, because it is not just a sudden reaction, it is due to his regard to islamic rules. and he should make tawba to(?) allah and say explanation of his behavior to persons who have seen it.